# Barycentric wireframes with full disclosure of back faces

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I've implemented a barycentric coordinates wireframe shader something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24839857/wireframe-shader-issue-with-barycentric-coordinates-when-using-shared-vertices), and in general it is working nicely.

But like [Florian Boesch's WebGL demo](http://codeflow.org/webgl/barycentric-wireframe/www/), some of the wire faces on the far side of the mesh are obscured (maybe has to do with the order in which the GPU is constructing faces).

I've set the following in the hopes that they would clear things up:

```
glCullFace(GL_NONE);
glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
```

...but no go so far. Is this possible in OpenGL ES 2.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had forgotten to `discard` on a transparent output, so the depth buffer was being written in spite of the apparently transparent geometry, thus the mesh was self-obscuring due to depth tests failing.

This would be the problem in Florian's demo too, though it may be that he explicitly avoids `discard` for [mobile performance reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8509051/is-discard-bad-for-program-performance-in-opengl).